# angularjs show table per field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show the results of a MySQL query on my website using angularjs. For now, I'm showing them using a simple table with ng-repeat and it works with no problem. But because the data is a lot, I wanted to ask if it is possible to create multiple panels or tables per specific field.

To be more specific, I have 4 fields returned from the query: name, address, occupation, department. Right now I have a table such as:

```
George Smith    Nikis 10      Project Manager    Finance
Maria Bexley    Lincoln 20    Project Manager    Research
Chris Liggs     Forks 123     Programmer         Computer Science
```

etc. I want to know if I can create as many panels or tables as the unique values of the "occupation" field are and then show the results per that unique value inside each panel/table. So instead of the above table I would have something like:

```
Project Manager
George Smith    Nikis 10    Finance
Maria Bexley    Lincoln 20   Research


Programmer
Chris Liggs     Forks 123  Computer Science
```

Comment: Yes you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use groupby filter

Check this fiddle by Darryl Rubarth, it contains the answer you need

http://jsfiddle.net/drubarth/R8YZh/

`<div ng-repeat="item in MyList  | orderBy:'groupfield' | groupBy:'groupfield'" >`

You can use group by filter in ng-repeat with which you need to group